# iOS + Web Services + Intranet

Tags: ios, web-services, wifi, intranet

On the mac, we can easily update the 'hosts' file and send a web-service hit to local server, and get the required data (faster). Can we do something similar if the Server and iOS application are both under the same Wifi network (for example)?

Comment: +1 Have you found any solution ? I need to open use intranet web services. Thanks

Comment: On the intranet, you'll have a local IP address for the machine which is serving your webservices. Just use that IP address instead of a web-url and you should be able to access the webservices (locally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a 'hosts' file for the iOS devices.  But you can use bonjour service to advertise your server over local WiFi network.  Your iOS app can use bonjour to discover such servers.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'll look into this server discovery using bonjour.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you could do to point your iPad to a local server even when accessing a global url is this, if I understand your question right:

1. Create a WIFI network on your Mac
2. Update the hosts file on your Mac and let the "global" address point to your local service
3. Now when you access the "global" address on your iPad it will go via your Mac and will therefore point to the local machine

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't think one has access to a kind of hosts file in iOS, but you can definitely access servers in your local network using Bonjour.

```
<hostname>.local
```